# SUM13 Coding bat exercise

Tags: python, for-in-loop

I am confused about an answer to a codingbat.com Python exercise.

The question is as follows:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

```
sum13([1, 2, 2, 1]) → 6
sum13([1, 1]) → 2
sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) → 6
```

The sample answer:

```
def sum13(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

for i in range(0, len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13:
        nums[i] = 0
    if i+1 < len(nums): 
        nums[i+1] = 0
    return sum(nums)
```

I do not understand what this means "if i+1 < len(nums)"

I understand it has something to do with the number in the array that comes after 13 being counted as 0 but what exactly does i+1 being less than the len of the array nums have to do with it?

I am new to Python and am trying to make sense of this but I do not get it.

Comment: It is a guard to check that we did not already reach the end of the list, since in that case, we would go out of bounds with `nums[i+1]`. Nevertheless, I do not like this implementation, it is rather *unpythonic*.

Comment: Is that exactly how the sample answer appears on the page? Because when I run it, I get `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: The problem description says "numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count". This implementation wants to do that by zeroing out the number after each 13. That's not quite the same thing, because if the last number is a 13, there _is_ no number that comes immediately after it to zero out. So it needs a check to handle that special case. This is actually a great lesson, even if not well taught—naive designs often have special cases (and especially so in places like the edges of a list) that aren't obvious at first, and that's where half your debugging time ends up being spent.

Comment: The sample answer also appears wrong because it won't zero out a value after a *repeated* 13: `[13, 13, 6]` gets turned into `[13, 0, 6]` after seeing the first 13, meaning the 6 will contribute to the sum when it (apparently) shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a list in an index that is equal or larger than the list's length. That `if` checks exactly that.